# mssql-jdbc always throws The authenticationScheme NTLM is not valid

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, ntlm

```
new SQLServerDriver();
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=<MYDOMAIN>;user=<user>;password=<password>;";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    String SQL = "select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

Here is my OS and Java version:

OS: Windows 10
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

Doesn't matter if the string is 'NTLM' or 'ntlm' etc this message:

> The authenticationScheme "" is not valid

It is definitely failing here
https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java#L245

Comment: Sorry, the only way I found to reproduce your error was to add `;authenticationScheme=\"\"` to the end of the connection string.  However, I note that the error message in your question title differs from that in the body your question, and I can reproduce that error if I include Unicode zero-width spaces (`\u200b`) within the text `NTLM`.  Is it possible that that's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It is resolved by using the latest jdbc driver version `mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar`. Also, ensure you have the dll file `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64.dll` placed in lib path.